# Get comma separated texts from comma separated ids

Tags: sql, oracle, csv

I have two tables, tblStudent and tblDepartment. I am storing DeptIds in student table in form of comma-separated values, for example -

```
StudentId  DeptIds
1          1,2,3
2          4
3          1,5
```

I want to get Department names separated by commas instead of DeptIds in my GetById procedure of student table. Any help please?

Comment: Create a cross table instead for your many-to-many relationship and store studentId and departmentId there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### First, change your data model for it not to include `DeptIds` CSV column values

It is extremely unpractical, as you can see by your problem, which would never occur with better data model.

**I would recommend the following data model:**

- tblStudent table with minimal student data (id, name, surname, date_of_birth...)
- tblDepartment table with minimal department data (id, dept_name, dept_group...)
- **tblStudentDept as middle table** with connecting data (StudentId, DeptId, ActivityInd, date_from, date_until...)

This way, you'd use `tblStudentDept` table to store your data about student roles in specific departments row-by-row:

```
ID  StudentId  DeptIds    
 1   1          1
 2   1          2
 3   1          3   
 4   2          4
 5   3          1
 6   3          5
```

### After that, you can show your CSV data using `LISTAGG` function

**For ID's, as you had before:**

Code with test data sample in `WITH AS`:

```
WITH tblStudentDept AS(
    select 1 as id, 1 as StudentID, 1 as DeptID from dual
    union all
    select 2 as id, 1 as StudentID, 2 as DeptID from dual
    union all
    select 3 as id, 1 as StudentID, 3 as DeptID from dual
    union all
    select 4 as id, 2 as StudentID, 4 as DeptID from dual
    union all
    select 5 as id, 3 as StudentID, 1 as DeptID from dual
    union all
    select 6 as id, 3 as StudentID, 5 as DeptID from dual
)
SELECT sd.StudentID, LISTAGG(DeptID, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY sd.DeptID)
  FROM tblStudentDept sd
 GROUP BY sd.StudentID;
```

**For Department names, as you have requested:**

Code with test data sample in `WITH AS`, using join between your `tblDepartment` table and hopefully newly-created `tblStudentDept` table:

```
WITH tblStudentDept AS(
    select 1 as id, 1 as StudentID, 1 as DeptID from dual
    union all
    select 2 as id, 1 as StudentID, 2 as DeptID from dual
    union all
    select 3 as id, 1 as StudentID, 3 as DeptID from dual
    union all
    select 4 as id, 2 as StudentID, 4 as DeptID from dual
    union all
    select 5 as id, 3 as StudentID, 1 as DeptID from dual
    union all
    select 6 as id, 3 as StudentID, 5 as DeptID from dual
),
tblDepartment AS(
    select 1 as DeptId, 'Dept-1' as DeptName from dual
    union all
    select 2 as DeptId, 'Dept-2' as DeptName from dual
    union all
    select 3 as DeptId, 'Dept-3' as DeptName from dual
    union all
    select 4 as DeptId, 'Dept-4' as DeptName from dual
    union all
    select 5 as DeptId, 'Dept-5' as DeptName from dual
)
SELECT sd.StudentID, LISTAGG(d.DeptName, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY sd.DeptID) as DeptNames
  FROM tblStudentDept sd
  JOIN tblDepartment d
    ON (d.DeptId = sd.DeptId)
 GROUP BY sd.StudentID;
```

Code output:

```
StudentId  DeptNames    
 1          Dept-1,Dept-2,Dept-3
 2          Dept-4
 3          Dept-1,Dept-5
```

**I hope I helped!**